# XBMCbuntu no gui after killing xbmc using kill -9

Tags: 12.10, xorg, xbmc

I have been using XBMCbuntu for quite some time now(Xbmc 12.2 and ubuntu 12.10 packed as xbmcbuntu). For coming to the login screen from xbmc, I tried Shutdown->Quit. But it did not work. All I got was blank screen. So I switched to terminal using `[Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1]` and did `ps aux | grep xbmc`. Then I killed all the filtered processes using `kill -9` command. Still the login screen did not come. But after this when I boot the machine, no gui comes up. I'm not even able to access the terminals via `[Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1]`. Currently I'm accessing the machine via ssh.

I understand killing a process just kills it and the process has no reason not come up again on reboot. But when I do `ps aux | grep xbmc` now after rebooting, there are no xbmc processes running.
Any idea why the gui is not coming up. From reading around, what I've come to know is the default session for lightdm is specified in [/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6672051/) file. Mine uses XBMC as the default session and the session is defined in [/usr/share/xsessions/XBMC.desktop](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6672054/). When I try starting `xbmc-standalone` on commandline via ssh, I get this [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6672071/). Any idea on which direction to proceed to fix this?

Here are some log files that I thought might be useful although I didn't see anything weird going on there:

1. [/var/log/boot.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6672021/)
2. [/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6672035/)
3. [/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6672043/)
4. [/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6672021/)

Comment: When you issued the `kill -9` command, did you append it with the `pid` of the process(es) you were trying to stop? Based on what I can tell from your log when trying to manually start XBMC, it can't find a display to use.

Comment: Ya I passed in all the pids that were output from `ps aux | grep xbmc`. Couldn't the reason for not being able to find the display be due to the fact that I'm accessing it via ssh and there might be non xsession in commandline?

Comment: One thing I noted is that since I killed those processes using `kill -9`, xbmc has not started during boot or atleast it has not been writing to the regular log location since the last modified time of `~/.xbmc/temp/xbmc.log` has not changed since I killed those processes although I have restarted the machine atleast 5 times after that.

Comment: My hunch is that the problem lies around `lightdm` somewhere. You're getting a successful login through it, but when XBMC starts it ends up killing the `lightdm` session. You might try some options for `lightdm` [listed here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) to see if at least you can get a GUI up and running.

Comment: @douggro You were right. The issue was with lightdm. After I uninstalled lightdm `sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm` atleast the 7 terminals [Ctrl] + [Alt] + F1-7 were working fine. Re-installing lightdm did not do the trick. I once again uninstalled lightdm and installed gdm after which the login page came up and I logged in to the XBMC session. Then I enabled automatic login as specified <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Automatic_login">here</a>. It seems a bit slower than lightdm. I'll try to get lightdm working over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After logging in via ssh, I observed that lightdm was not running using the command `sudo status lightdm`. Starting lightdm using `sudo start lightdm` showed the lightdm process was getting killed immediately after it starts. Looking at /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log I saw a line similar to `Process exited with signal 6`. Purging lightdm and re-installing it did not fix the issue and the same problem persisted. I then uninstalled lightdm and installed gdm. The login page came up and then I set up auto login for the xbmc session as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Automatic_login). The media center was back to perfection as before. But login with gdm seems to be a tad bit slower than it was with lightdm.

Comment: A week ago I pulled the machines power cord without shutting it down. Next time I started, there was no display after the xbmc loading screen. Again I purged gdm and reinstalled it again. Then it started working.